# Installing Qt on Snow Leopard fails

Tags: macos, qt, installation, osx-snow-leopard

I am having a hard time trying to get Qt running. I downloaded the 4.6.2 SDK-Installer and it completed successfully. Yet, when I try to compile any of the examples by Terminal and typing "qmake" I get errors like this

```
Failure to read QMAKESPEC conf file /Users/xxx/mkspecs/macx-g++/qmake.conf.
Error processing project file: /Users/xxx/chap06/mdieditor/mdieditor.pro
```

I tried adding

```
#qt
export PATH='/usr/local/Qt4.6':$PATH
export QTDIR=’/usr/local/Qt4.6‘
export QMAKESPEC=/usr/local/Qt4.6/mkspecs/macx-g++
```

to my .profile file, I get another error, stating

```
Project LOAD(): Feature qt_config cannot be found.
```

Do you have any idea what went wrong in the installation?

Thank you very much for your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
export PATH='/usr/local/Qt4.6/bin':$PATH
```

instead.

Comment: hm, this folder does not exist on my machine ... is that a bad sign?

Comment: Not sure, I've never installed the SDK before. I always just get the source and build that manually. What's in the /usr/local/Qt4.6 folder then? Also what's the result of typing `which qmake`?